# Less/more info on profile page mucks up winter bash hats

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, winter-bash-2012, winter-bash-2013

Two issues here.

---

Firstly, the hat isn't shown in less info profile view.

To reproduce navigate to the profile page of someone with a hat and click `Less Info` (if it's not already in that view).

---

Secondly, if you go to the page and it defaults to the less info view and you then click more info the hat is in the top left not on my profile picture.

To reproduce navigate to the profile page of someone with a hat and ensure you are in `Less Info` view mode. Navigate back to the profile page.

After opening any profile page (when default view is "less info"):

> [image]

After clicking on "more info":

> [image]

This can be reproduced in Winterbash 2013 too.

Comment: They'll be gone on Friday anyway :'(

Comment: There needs to be a userscript to bring back hats!!!

Comment: True, not a particularly well-timed bug report, but maybe useful as a heads-up for next year!

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett did you mean "useful as a hats-up"?

Comment: Voted to reopen, issue can be reproduced in this winterbash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Winter Bash 2013 I've fixed this; hats now work correctly for both the big and the small version, and for toggling between them.

Comment: Great! Thank you for fixing very fast.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unable to reproduce this, what hats are you talking about???

Comment: what even is hats.

Comment: If I remember correctly it was the cake hat. Think that was the last hat I was wearing.

Comment: Just realised you are joking.... doh!

Comment: This is reproducible. I was about to ask the same question. But found it by searching. Please have a look at the steps to reproduce.

Comment: @hims056 This was a joke. The answer was posted after Winter Bash 2012 was over.