# Why is clicking on reputation in profile showing me my hats?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

Whenever I click my reputation on my profile to view rep changes. I get shown my hats instead.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: you are talking about this link http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/227817/christmas-unicorn?tab=reputation or something else ?

Comment: @Bala Check my update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Because bug. Fixed now.

Comment: Sir balpha, This bug is back

Comment: Ooops, I broke it again when I fixed [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161165/less-more-info-on-profile-page-mucks-up-winter-bash-hats). Repaired again, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks! Thanks!! Thanks!!!